# Union of finitely generated submodule is a finitely generated submodule??

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A_i$ be a finitely generated submodule of $M$, for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}A_i$
is a finitely generated submodule of $M$.

I know for normal submodule this is not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\Bbb Q^{(\Bbb N)}:=\{f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb Q\,\mid\, \left\lvert\Bbb N\setminus f^{-1}(0)\right\rvert<\aleph_0\}$ is not finitely generated as a $\Bbb Q$-module, yet $\Bbb Q^{(\Bbb N)}=\bigcup_{x\in\Bbb Q^{(\Bbb N)}} \Bbb Qx$. This is a counterexample to your claim because $\left\lvert\Bbb Q^{(\Bbb N)}\right\rvert=\aleph_0$.

Answer (score 1):

The union of submodules is in general not a submodule.

But the result is false even if you make the further assumption that $A_i\subseteq A_{i+1}$ for all $i$, in which case the union is indeed a submodule.

Consider the [Prüfer $p$-group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group): its proper submodules are finite (hence finitely generated) and form a countable ascending chain, but their union is the whole group, which is not finitely generated.

Actually, the union of a countable ascending chain of submodules is finitely generated if and only if there is $k$ such that, for all $i>k$, $A_i=A_k$.